# Show that every Cauchy sequence which admits a convergent subsequence is also convergent. Is my proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$. Suppose that there is some subsequence $(x_{f(n)})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ of this sequence which converges to a limit $x_{0}\in X$. Then the original sequence $(x_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ also converges to $x_{0}$.

**My solution**

To begin with, notice that
\begin{align*}
d(x_{n},x_{0}) \leq d(x_{n},x_{f(n)}) + d(x_{f(n)},x_{0})
\end{align*}

Let $\varepsilon/2 > 0$. Since $x_{n}$ is Cauchy, there is a natural number $N_{1}\geq m$ such that
\begin{align*}
n'\geq n \geq N_{1} \Rightarrow d(x_{n'},x_{n}) < \varepsilon/2
\end{align*}

Once $f(n)$ is strictly increasing, we have that $f(n)\geq n$. Thus for every $n\geq N_{1}$, we have that
\begin{align*}
f(n)\geq n \geq N_{1} \Rightarrow d(x_{n},x_{f(n)}) < \varepsilon/2
\end{align*}

But we do also know that $x_{f(n)}\to x_{0}$. Consequently, there corresponds a natural $N_{2}\geq m$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N_{2} \Rightarrow d(x_{f(n)},x_{0}) < \varepsilon/2
\end{align*}

Gathering both results, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there corresponds a $N = \max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Rightarrow d(x_{n},x_{0}) \leq d(x_{n},x_{f(n)}) + d(x_{f(n)},x_{0}) < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
and we are done.

I am mainly concerned with the wording of the proof. Can someone point out any flaw?

Comment: The use of the wording "Once $x_n$ is Cauchy..." and "Once $f(n)$ is strictly increasing..." should perhaps be changed to "Since $x_n$ is Cauchy..." and "Since $f(n)$ is strictly increasing..."

Comment: "for every $N_2 \geq m$" - I think you mean that there *exists* an $N_2 \geq m$ such that...

Comment: What is the use of $m$ in your proof? All you need to say is that "there is a natural number $N_1$ such that..."

Comment: Indeed, @NicholasRoberts, you are right. It is just a (formal) convention from the book which I am reading.

Comment: @EagerToLearn Out of curiosity, which book are you reading from?

Comment: @AbhijeetVats I am reading Analysis II from Terence Tao.